# Is CWnd::GetSafeHwnd() and CWnd::m_hWnd ThreadSafe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, thread-safety, thread-local-storage

I am facing numerous crashes on a application which is heavily multi-threaded.

Reading these MSDN [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/h14y172e.aspx), [technical note](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/c251x6s1.aspx) and [this article on TLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms686749.aspx), I have understood that `CWnd` objects are mapped to HWND in the Thread Local Storgae (TLS, which is a thread dependendent memory access).

I was going to decouple everything that looks like CWnd thread-remote access, and transform it into `HWND` references and then use `::PostMessage` as communication port.

But one of my colleagues really insisted that I just keep the `CWnd*` in the foreigner threads, adopt the `::PostMessage` policy ok, but use `CWnd::GetSafeHwnd()` or the `pMyCWnd->m_hWnd` in the foreign threads so as to recover the native `HWND`.

I have been arguing that **nowhere** I have seen that the `GetSafeHwnd()` is threadsafe, and that the `CWnd` objet being in the TLS, it's value in another thread is different.

I am wrong ? The MSDN is clearly using the term **Unexpected results**.

What's your point of view, about calling `CWnd::GetSafehwnd()` or `pMyCWnd->m_hWnd` in outer threads from the creator thread ?

Do you have any MSDN documentation that states that this is safe or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CWnds are not mapped to HWNDs; HWNDs are mapped to CWnds, and this happens on a per-thread basis.  The CWnd object is not in TLS (how would that work?) but temporary CWnd objects are created per-thread.

Accessing a *temporary* CWnd object from the wrong thread is definitely a bad idea (for the reasons described by Mark Ransom).

However, if you have a permanent CWnd object (representing the main window of your app, say) then, once it is created, there is no problem at all in accessing the m_hWnd member from any thread.  It's just a value in memory that never changes.

If this troubles you (because it's not explicitly documented) then simply make a copy of the HWND and let the threads access that.

P.S. [Here's the article you linked to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h14y172e.aspx) in English.

Answer (score 5):

GetSafeHwnd is simply a wrapper that checks if `this` is NULL, returns `m_hWnd` if not and NULL if it is. It won't be any more threadsafe than `m_hWnd` itself.

When you create a temporary CWnd*, MFC will destroy it at a point it considers safe, such as the next pass through the message loop. If you have multiple threads using MFC then your temporary object could get destroyed while you're still using it. Nothing you can do from your thread will detect this error.

Comment: are all CWnd* temporaries or not ? I mean the one CWnd* created in the creator thread when instanciating the window, is it temporary too ??? ( I mean not the ones computed through a CWnd::FromHandle() )

Answer (score 1):

If you have a multithreaded application where multiple threads are all trying to access HWNDs at once, it sounds to me like you have a design problem. Can't you constrain your threads to doing computation, and handle UI concerns on the main thread? That's the typical design of a good multithreaded app.

Comment: Nice advice, but I can't recode the whole thing,many LOC, and it is more than 10 years old, there's a huge history I can't wipe it away :-)

Comment: Well, your question is basically "I have to do this extremely unsafe thing, is it safe?" And the answer is probably that "nothing will make it safe." You can make it *safer* to a degree, but I doubt it can be made crash-free in the current design.

Comment: (BTW, I can relate. I also work on a 10 year old MFC codebase. Thank God we don't have threads; the original coders were not nearly smart enough to have gotten that right.)

Comment: I don't agree with your statement. If I do ::PostMessage on HWND it looks a little safer, since it is the thread of the pumping message window that wil perform the update. Maybe not the best design, i agreee totally. My Question is basically **"Is GetSafeHwnd() or CWnd::m_hWnd Threadsafe"**, to which you have not answered. ;-).

Comment: It is just returning a member variable IIRC. It is probably possible to use it in thread-safe code, but it's obviously unsafe if, for example, a thread calls it while the window is mid-create or mid-destroy. So it depends on your circumstances.

Comment: Oh, and as others have mentioned, temporary CWnd*s are extremely unsafe. In fact I consider them fairly unsafe in single-threaded code as well.